# Is there a way to tell Stata to execute the whole do-file ignoring the lines producing exceptions (or even syntax errors)?

Tags: execution, stata

I run the time-consuming code in the background and oftentimes even the 10% of the code is not executed due to a small syntax mistake in the beginning of the do-file.

I would prefer the rest of the do-file to be executed as well since sometimes that mistake in the beginning has no effect on the computations at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(version 2)

Wanting Stata to ignore mistakes can itself be mistaken.

1. If there is a mistake early in a do-file, it usually has implications for what follows.
2. Suppose you got Stata to work as you wish. How do you know whether Stata ignored something important or something trivial? If it ignored something trivial, that should be easy to fix. If it ignored something important, that was the wrong decision.

Let's now be more constructive. The help for `do` tells you that there is a `nostop` option. 
You need to be very careful about how you use it, but it can help here.

The context of `do, nostop` is precisely that of the OP. People had do-files, often expected to take a long time because of big datasets or lots of heavy computation, and set them going, historically "overnight" or "while you went to lunch". Then they would be irritated to find that the do-file had quickly terminated on the first error, and especially irritated if the error was trivial. So, the idea of `do, nostop` is to `do` as much as you can, but as an aid to debugging. For example, suppose you got a variable name wrong in various places; you `generate Y` but refer to `y` later, which doesn't exist. You might expect to find corresponding error messages scattered through the file, which you can fix. The error messages are the key here.

The point about do files is that once they are right, you can save yourself lots of time, but no-one ever promised that getting the do-file right in the first place would always be easy.

My firm advice is: Fix the bugs; don't try to ignore them.

P.S. `capture` was mentioned in another answer. `capture` may seem similar in spirit, but used in similar style it can be a bad idea.

`capture` eats error messages, so the user doesn't see them. For debugging, that is the opposite of what is needed.

`capture` is really a programmer's command, and its uses are where the programmer is being smart on behalf of the user and keeping quiet about it.

Suppose, for example, a variable supplied could be numeric or it could be string. If it's numeric, we need to do A; if it's string we need to do B. (Either A or B could be "nothing".) There could be branches like this.

```
  capture confirm str variable myvar 
  if _rc { /// it's numeric 
       <do A> 
  } 
  else { 
       <do B> 
  }
```

Otherwise put, `capture` is for handling predictable problems if and as they arise. It is not for ignoring bugs.

Comment: +1 Second that @Nick. The do file should run itself without Stata complaining and it really pays off to fix even the small bugs. Both for you to be sure you are doing right things, and perhaps for othes that will one day try to reuse your code! That is actually the feature of Stata that I prefer compared to, fo instance R - being rather a noob I often find myself doing mistakes that give no or wrong results.. and R will continue execution of the script.

Answer (score 1):

If there are only a couple commands that are hanging up and are otherwise inconsequential to your later calculations, you can always use `capture` (either as an inline prefix or as a block command, see `help capture` on use) to force the program to run through commands that stop the program.

But--echoing Nick's general comments about this way of writing and executing do-files--be similarly careful where you apply `capture`: generally, you should only apply it to commands you are sure would not affect later code or calculations. Or, even better, just remove from the program those lines that are giving problems and you apparently don't need anyway.

Comment: Good advice. I've strengthened the advice in my own answer. (What I've said would not fit into a comment.)

Comment: Yes. @NickCox highlights an important distinction between `,nostop` option and `capture` command that I did not. `capture` should never be used if there is a need to debug (it is useless in that case).